# Java - Replace regex occurrences in a string

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I have to replace all occurrences of ")(" in a string by " ", and then, delete all the occurrences of "(" and ")".
For example : (1,1)(2,2) => (1,1 2,2) => 1,1 2,2. 
I've tried this for the first step but the string wasn't changed:

```
String test = "(1,1)(2,2)";
test.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(")("), Pattern.quote(" "));
```

Comment: `"[\()]"` works no?

Answer (score 0):

`String`s are immutable. Simply calling `replaceAll` does not modify the string, but returns a new one. You need to do

```
String test = "(1,1)(2,2)";
test = test.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(")("), " ");
```

or use the `replace` method not working with regex for simplicity

```
String test = "(1,1)(2,2)";
test = test.replace(")(", " ");
```